# Bootstrap Modal changes body size after closing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.5 and after closing any modal my body gets it size reduced by few pixels.

As I was reading on github, that was an old issue that was fixed in the last year. Does anyone know how to prevent and/or how to avoid this issue?

Comment: If you're truly using 3.3.5 (which was released yesterday), then you may have come across a regression. I would recommend having a look through [Bootstrap's issue tracker](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) and seeing if you can find the previous one and then potentially submit an issue informing them.

Comment: I got the same issue on 3.3.2 also, so I dont think thats a regression issue.

Comment: Are you loading anything else? Rather, could you post some code that can reproduce the issue? Ideally with as little other elements as possible.

Comment: Post the full code of your webpage!

Comment: This might sound like a daft question - though are you sure it's not a scrollbar hiding when the modal is open, and coming back when it's closed? - there is a `class="modal-open"` added to the body when you open a modal. this has an overflow hidden on it.